# A foreign exchange reserves

Tags: bonds, interest

A foreign exchange reserves manager is indifferent between placing a deposit in a foreign bank account or paying $98 to purchase a $100 zero issued by an advanced country government that matures in one year. What is the interest rate offered by the bank account?

do not know how to calculate it

Comment: Do you know what a "zero" is? Or how interest is calculated?

Comment: Price = M ÷ (1 + r)n

Comment: but i do not know how to proceed because i do not have the interest, I do not know if treating it as x i can get up to 0,21%?

Comment: You know `Price` (98), `M` (100) and `n` (1). So you can reverse the algebra to find `r`

Answer (score 1):

zero = Zero-coupon bond

Interest rate of the zero-coupon bond = (100-98)/98 = 2.04%

The buyer pays $98 today to buy the bond, and gets $100 upon maturity.

Comment: thank you so much:)